# How to ignore json elements when a nested array has an key:value matching patterm?

Tags: json, api, command-line-interface, jq

I have been using jq(1) and getting a similar response back from a kubernetes api (api/v1/nodes).

```
{
  "kind": "NodeList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes",
    "resourceVersion": "8768"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes/ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "uid": "2l3kje2ili-23e232-2e3ee-edwed-232398h9e3h98h",
        "resourceVersion": "8768",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-11-19T12:27:05Z",
          },
      "spec": {
        "podCIDR": "101.191.101.101/24",
        "providerID": "aws:///us-west-1e/i-lidss9jsjldsjli",
        "taints": [
          {
            "key": "worker-group",
            "value": "prometheus",
            "effect": "NoSchedule"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see there can be many **items** in the Array. There are some with the .spec.taints and others without it. Some may be empty and some may be full.

My goal is to just ignore all items that have the taints `"effect": "NoSchedule"`

I'm finding this very troublesome because no matter what I try and I've been searching online for days, i can't get it to work properly.

I've gotten this far but am now stuck

`curl api | jq -c '.items[].spec.taints |= map(select(.effect | . != "NoSchedule"))'`

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question would be clearer if it followed the [mcve] guidelines more closely. That would also make the Q&A as a whole more helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This deletes from the `.items` array every member that has an array in `.spec.taints` which in turn has at least one object item with `.effect` set to `"NoSchedule"`. In every other case, i.e. there's only objects with `.effect` set to something else, or `.taints` is empty, or there's no `.taints` at all, or there's no `.spec` at all, up to just an empty object `{}` as member of the `.items` array, that array member will be retained.

```
.items -= (.items | map(select(.spec.taints[].effect == "NoSchedule")?))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/u7lhoa7Kss)

Comment: Thanks so much. This one worked lovely

Answer (score 1):

You can use `del` to delete the one(s) you intended :

```
curl api | jq 'del(.items[] | select(.spec.taints[].effect == "NoSchedule")?)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be useful, in this example there are 3 items one with effect: NoSchedule, one with effect: anyother and one with taints empty. If am correct, you need only the second one:

```
{
  "kind": "NodeList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes",
    "resourceVersion": "8768"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes/ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "uid": "2l3kje2ili-23e232-2e3ee-edwed-232398h9e3h98h",
        "resourceVersion": "8768",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-11-19T12:27:05Z"
          },
      "spec": {
        "podCIDR": "101.191.101.101/24",
        "providerID": "aws:///us-west-1e/i-lidss9jsjldsjli",
        "taints": [
          {
            "key": "worker-group",
            "value": "prometheus",
            "effect": "NoSchedule"
          }
        ]
      }
    },

  {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes/ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "uid": "2l3kje2ili-23e232-2e3ee-edwed-232398h9e3h98h",
        "resourceVersion": "8768",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-11-19T12:27:05Z"
          },
      "spec": {
        "podCIDR": "101.191.101.101/24",
        "providerID": "aws:///us-west-1e/i-lidss9jsjldsjli",
        "taints": [
          {
            "key": "worker-group",
            "value": "prometheus",
            "effect": "anyother"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes/ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
        "uid": "2l3kje2ili-23e232-2e3ee-edwed-232398h9e3h98h",
        "resourceVersion": "8768",
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-11-19T12:27:05Z"
          },
      "spec": {
        "podCIDR": "101.191.101.101/24",
        "providerID": "aws:///us-west-1e/i-lidss9jsjldsjli",
        "taints": [

        ]
      }
    }


  ]
```

**The command will be:**

```
 jq '.items[]|select(.spec.taints[].effect!="NoSchedule") ' data1.jtxt
```

result:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes/ip-101-191-101-101.ec2.internal",
    "uid": "2l3kje2ili-23e232-2e3ee-edwed-232398h9e3h98h",
    "resourceVersion": "8768",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-11-19T12:27:05Z"
  },
  "spec": {
    "podCIDR": "101.191.101.101/24",
    "providerID": "aws:///us-west-1e/i-lidss9jsjldsjli",
    "taints": [
      {
        "key": "worker-group",
        "value": "prometheus",
        "effect": "anyother"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note: I put your data ina a file to simulate input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, my understanding is that the `taints` could have multiple entries. It could be a mix of `NoSchedule` and other values. Here's the `jq` where the item will be ignored if at least one taint with `effect` value `NoSchedule` exists.

````
. as $in | $in * { items: $in.items | map(select(.spec.taints | all(.effect != "NoSchedule"))) }```
````